# How to implemtent two different searchs in one activity

Tags: android, search

I am developing an android app, in which an activity has to implement two different search functions. If i write two different searchable activities, then how to integrate them in manifest file. or can we write two search functions in same  searchable activity.
Please help me out. How to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".SearchResultsImageActivity" />
```

when you will trigger native search in YourActivity it will invoke the SearchResultsImageActivity and default one for others.

Assuming SearchResultsImageActivity is searchable